# how to make a iterable object like this?

Tags: python, list

Question 1

how to make an iterable object like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 ....
```

Question 2

if use list(obj) on the object above would this eat up machine's memory? how to prevent it?

Please don't use python2

Comment: thank you ill make two questions

Comment: Also, if this is homework, we appreciate it if you use the `homework` tag so we can help you learn instead of just handing over the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an infinite generator that counts up and down:

```
def updown(n):
    while True:
        for i in range(n):
            yield i
        for i in range(n - 2, 0, -1):
            yield i

uptofive = updown(6)
for i in range(20):
    print uptofive.next(),
```

would output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
```

You cannot prevent `list(updown(6))` from trying to consume all memory, no. As the doctor would say: "Then don't do that!".

Use `.next()` calls instead, or use your generator with another statement that limits the number of times you iterate over the generator. The [`itertools.islice()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) would do just that:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.islice(updown(6), 20))
```

Comment: You have a duplicate "5" in there.

Comment: In Python 2, `xrange` might be a bit better in this context.

Comment: @cdarke: for small ranges, don't bother, and it'll keep it portable with minimum fuss.

Comment: @mhawke: What dupe 5? *innocent whistle*

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm afraid that later comers will not see the joke :)

Comment: Spoiler alert: `(n - 1)` changed to `(n - 2)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't violently disagree, but the op specifically asked about iterable objects, and might extend your code to a larger range if this was just a sample.  Anyway the `print` breaks portability to Py3.

Comment: @Max: Only the print line won't work in 3; use `print(next(uptofive), end='')` in 3.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `itertools.cycle()`:

```
from itertools import cycle

def oscillator(start, stop):
    # assumes stop >= start
    return cycle(range(start, stop+1) + range(stop-1, start, -1))

o = oscillator(0, 5)
for i in range(30):
    print o.next(),
```